# Mails from my website goes to spam folder

Tags: email, dns, gmail, spam, spf

This is a result from isnotspam.com

## ========================================================== Summary of Results

SPF Check : softfail Sender-ID Check : neutral DomainKeys Check : neutral DKIM Check : neutral SpamAssassin Check : ham (non-spam)

## ========================================================== Details:

HELO hostname: in6.hostgator.in Source IP: 119.18.60.5 mail-from: info@propertyfirst.in Anonymous To: ins-kgqo0hhz@isnotspam.com

### --------------------------------------------------------- SPF check details:

Result: softfail ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=info@propertyfirst.in DNS record(s): propertyfirst.in.   14394   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all"

### ---------------------------------------------------------- Sender-ID check details:

Result: neutral

ID(s) verified: smtp.mail=info@propertyfirst.in DNS record(s): propertyfirst.in.    14394   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all"

### ---------------------------------------------------------- DomainKeys check details:

Result: neutral (message not signed) ID(s) verified: header.From=info@propertyfirst.in Selector= domain= DomainKeys DNS Record=

### ---------------------------------------------------------- DKIM check details:

Result: neutral (message not signed) ID(s) verified: header.From=info@propertyfirst.in Selector= domain= DomainKeys DNS Record=

---------------------------------------------------------- SpamAssassin check details:
---------------------------------------------------------- SpamAssassin v3.3.1 (2010-03-19)

Result: ham (non-spam) (05.9points, 10.0 required)

pts rule name description

---

Can someone please tell me what is the issue here and what spf and how do I set it up.

Will setting up a spf help me in anyways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, an SPF SoftFail can cause your email to be classified as spam.

Judging from the current state of the TXT record for propertyfirst.in, you have already figured it out on your own, but for future reference, SPF is a way for the domain administrator to designate hosts as legitimate senders for the domain in question. The policy is published in DNS using a TXT or SPF RR.

In this particular case, the SPF policy of propertyfirst.in did not designate your web server 119.18.60.5 as a permitted sender. Consequently, emails from your web server were considered to be forged and marked as spam.

Your current SPF policy is `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:119.18.60.5 +include:propertyfirst.in ~all`, which explicitly permits 119.18.60.5 to send emails in the name of propertyfirst.in.

By the way you can lose the "+" PASS qualifiers, SPF mechanisms default to that.

Comment: thanks. But issue got resolved by removing few words from the mail which were included in the blacklist, which was causing it to go to spam. Editing the content was enough though

Comment: @jash389: Thanks for the update. In any case, the SPF policy has changed from `v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all` to `v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:119.18.60.5 +include:propertyfirst.in ~all`, so I suppose that could have played a role here.